# Java Regex for finding *(*007*)* not working, would love some advice

Tags: java, regex, junit

I am trying to implement a method to accept a string of characters and resolve to true if it contains: anything followed by "(" followed by anything followed by 007 followed by anything followed by ")" followed by anything.

In other words: `*(*007*)*`

My current pattern looks like this:

```
Pattern.compile("\\*\\s\\(\\s\\*\\s(0\\s0\\s7\\s)\\*\\s\\)\\*");
```

However, it is failing around 84 of my 229 junit test cases

Comment: the single \ in my op should be double\, it must have escaped to one when i posted

Comment: Why all the `\s`'s when your post mentions nothing about spaces?

Comment: What are the test cases? Note you may use http://regex101.com to test these kinds of expressions.

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't it just be something as simple as

```
.*\(.*007.*\).*
```

[See it in action](http://rubular.com/r/HKdVKYpo43).

Escaped for Java

```
.compile(".*\\(.*007.*\\).*")
```

Some test cases:

```
String pattern = ".*\\(.*007.*\\).*";

Assert.assertFalse("(006)".matches(pattern));
Assert.assertFalse("007".matches(pattern));

Assert.assertTrue("hi(this007is)me".matches(pattern));
Assert.assertTrue("hi(007)".matches(pattern));
```